# SOAP XML MESSAGE Generator

Tags: python-2.7, wsdl, soap-client

I need to create a generic SOAP-client module . It should get the wsdl link, function name, parameters as the input through a function and return the response.
I am struggling to create the XML SOAP message for each function.  Is there any dedicated python module that could create complete SOAP XML messages from a WSDL file??

```
from zeep import Client
client = Client(wsdlpath)
d ={ "id" : "****" , "password":"****"}
session=client.service["Login"](**d)
```

This is part of wat i tried for 1 wsdl file. The login fails as wsdl specific header is missing in the generated SOAP message. Also if complex type need to be included in the SOAP message , it requires wsdl specific code. Is there any way to generate the SOAP XML for a given wsdl file and function so that i can perform other send/receive actions using other xml tools and requests module itself.

Comment: This is possible duplicate. with python.27 there are many libs available to use such as pysimplesoap, suds, etc. google it many solutions are available there

Comment: The available solutions i could see are not producing the complete SOAP Message template  for a given function .

Comment: What do you think, whats missing out there?

Comment: I am not much aware on what they provide. May be i could not search what i want. Can you direct me to get something tat could fetch me SOAP message for a function in a wsdl

Comment: Can you show some code excerpt? I will guide you

Comment: Updated question

Comment: I am expecting to generate xml templates like what soapui gives. so that i  can fill them and send as required.

Comment: What's on your server side? SOAP server should generate the wsdl for you

Comment: I have wsdl.i want to  Auto generate soap xml message for each function.

Comment: SOAP Server does the job you looking out then, however you can generate them at your own by parsing wsdl. This would help you http://effbot.org/zone/element-soap.htm